# Angular data initialization via API

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out the logic for what I assume is a common issue.

Currently, I have a factory that on request, gets data about the currently logged in user. I recently learned about the run block, and figured I should move the code to there, but I realized it would face the same problem I am now: async data.

I have my API setup on a subdomain of my main site, so it counts as a cross domain request. As far as I've been able to see, there's no way to get Angular to make a synchronous request, and I thought to use the jQuery .ajax function, using the async parameter, but it says it doesn't work with cross domain requests.

I'm at a bit of a loss. Right now, I'm just doing a simple data object, and its pretty fast. But as my app grows, I'm sure I'll want to do more initialization, and I need that to finish before my app continues. How can I do this, or how should I be setting up my app to get around this?

Comment: I don't clearly understand your problem (maybe some code...), but in Angular,js you could wait to display templates, until your async data are retrieved, thanks to [route system and resolve options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

Comment: I actually found out about route and it's waiting yesterday, but in my case, I'm not using route as I'm adding Angular into an existing site, page by page, until I redo the site when my new design is ready.

Comment: So you have a fresh new Angular.js app in each page. Anyway you could use resolve in a single-route configuration or use [custom boostrap logic](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)